# Permisson error when using hand-crafted access tokens for the Simple OAuth (OAuth2) & OpenID Connect Drupal module

Tags: oauth-2.0, drupal

I am writing a Python service that integrates with a Drupal database. I need
to generate OAuth2 access tokens in Python, rather than calling the `/oauth2/token`
endpoint of the Drupal service, as this service is inaccessible.

There are two access tokens: 74127 and 74145.

- 74127 was created using the
  [Simple OAuth (OAuth2) & OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) Drupal module.
- 74145 was created using SQL

The 'Simple OAuth (OAuth2) & OpenID Connect' module creates two tables, `oauth2_token` and `oauth2_token__scopes`.
The following are records for the two access token records.

#### oauth2_token records

The access token records:

```
MySQL [db]> select * from oauth2_token where auth_user_id=189 and bundle='access_token';
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| id    | bundle       | uuid                                 | auth_user_id | client | value                                                                            | created    | changed    | expire     | status |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| 74127 | access_token | 40d0a3cb-4eea-4553-a65c-aafef2f7457e |          189 |      1 | 799b6f294d777f17f74b00c0c06c2889a2082db4193fa099bef19445e9ddb14159ca655db34feb28 | 1665143613 | 1665143613 | 1667562813 |      1 |
| 74145 | access_token | ae63b832-2a1b-4545-9e91-c3554b922ce0 |          189 |      1 | b03fd9a699030a37c97b097c8365537023dcd0faf2828f2761b2b9b61847cf10446134c185c10313 | 1665158898 | 1665158898 | 1667562813 |      1 |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

#### oauth2_token__scope records

The associated scope records:

```
MySQL [db]> select * from oauth2_token__scopes where entity_id=74127 or entity_id=74145;
+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------+
| bundle       | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | langcode | delta | scopes_target_id |
+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------+
| access_token |       0 |    74127  |       74127 | und      |     0 | authenticated    |
| access_token |       0 |    74145  |       74145 | und      |     0 | authenticated    |
+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

#### 74127 - created by Drupal module

The header for the decoded JWT for 74127 is:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "jti": "799b6f294d777f17f74b00c0c06c2889a2082db4193fa099bef19445e9ddb14159ca655db34feb28",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

and the body is:

```
{
  "aud": "40d0a3cb-4eea-4553-a65c-aafef2f7457e",
  "jti": "799b6f294d777f17f74b00c0c06c2889a2082db4193fa099bef19445e9ddb14159ca655db34feb28",
  "iat": 1665143613,
  "nbf": 1665143613,
  "exp": 1667562813,
  "sub": "189",
  "scope": [
    "authenticated"
  ]
}
```

Using this access token to get a protected resource results in a `200` response with the
resouce contents.

#### 74145 - created by SQL

The same method is used to create the JWT for 74145. It's header is

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "jti": "b03fd9a699030a37c97b097c8365537023dcd0faf2828f2761b2b9b61847cf10446134c185c10313",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

and the body is:

```
{
  "aud": "ae63b832-2a1b-4545-9e91-c3554b922ce0",
  "jti": "b03fd9a699030a37c97b097c8365537023dcd0faf2828f2761b2b9b61847cf10446134c185c10313",
  "iat": 1665143613,
  "nbf": 1665143613,
  "exp": 1667562813,
  "sub": "189",
  "scope": [
    "authenticated"
  ]
}
```

But, using this access token to get a protected resource results in a `403` response:

```
{
    "message": "The 'restful get digicel_user_details' permission is required."
}
```

#### Question

Given the database records for both access tokens are equivalent, why does 74145
get a `403` response? Is there some other record required to link that record to
a user permission somehow?